# Oneplus 6 viewport size for chrome Emulated Devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-testing

I would like to add OnePlus 6 as custom devices in the emulated devices list of Google Chrome but I don't manage to find:

- Device pixel ratio
- User agent string

[image: Missing params for device pixel ratio & user agent for oneplus 6 emeulated device in chrome]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For more information you can check out [this page](https://www.handsetdetection.com/device-detection-database/devices/oneplus/a6000/).

According to that page:

> - width x height: 568x320
> - Device pixel ratio: 2.6252

For user agent though, they list many. The one I use is:

> - User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; ONEPLUS A6000 Build/PKQ1.180716.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>     Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.64 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: Hi, @Javier Thanks for the answer. Just one query. In the link that you have provided the size mentioned there is 'display css screen sizes - 568x320'. I don't know if it has changed or something, but you have mentioned the size as 414x736 (736x414).

Answer (score 7):

Use this details

width x height: 412x869

Device pixel ratio: 1.00

> User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; ONEPLUS A6000
>   Build/PKQ1.180716.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.64 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: That's what my Chrome Browser says, too (with http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/).
However Firefox Mobile states 414 x 844 points.

Comment: Same for Chrome, but in reality not all of the vertical height is available on my device due to the back, home, and app buttons.